# Long derivative exercises: where to find them?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, learning

I am preparing for an exam. On the exam I will be asked to find the derivative of a long function, with a multiple chain rule. Such as:
$$y = (\frac{3}{x} - 2^{{x}^3})^{6} + \frac{\ln \sin \frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{5}}- x \arcsin \sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt[4]{x^{5}}} $$

I want to practice solving such derivatives, but nowhere could I find such examples. I was googling and checking on YouTube for "hard derivative problems", "difficult derivatives", "multiple chain rule", etc. I only found shorter, simpler examples.

Would anyone be able to point out to me where can I find some .pdfs with answers or YT videos to such derivatives? The exam is in 2 days and I won't be able to buy a book by now.

Thanks.

Comment: Just invent your own functions by composing various functions as you did in the post. Then check on [wolframalpha.com](https://wolframalpha.com) or on [derivative-calculator.net](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/). The latter has a free way to show all intermediate steps.

Comment: Here's some for you, hope they are useful: https://math.berkeley.edu/~kruckman/fall2010/9-29-problems.pdf

Comment: How about this generator? https://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/derivs.html

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to your exam but I remember doing multiple choice tests where asked to find the value of the derivative of such long functions for a specified x. I would use the limit definition with a very small h (.0001) which was accurate enough to determine the correct answer choice.